# ERROR-java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1)

Tags: java, mysql

this in my part of the code

```
Connection conn;
Connct readerconn = new Connct();
conn =readerconn.getConnection();
     
    
try{
    String query2="INSERT INTO issue (Submit_Date) SELECT Book_ID FROM issue WHERE Book_ID =?";
    PreparedStatement pstnt2=conn.prepareStatement(query2);
        
    pstnt2.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt( jTextField4.getText()));
        
    java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(jXDatePicker1.getDate().getTime());
    pstnt2.setDate(2,  (date));
    pstnt2.executeUpdate();
        
    showMessageDialog(null, "Saved");
        
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ReturnNFines.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    showMessageDialog(null, "Failed");
}
```

i'm getting error when clicked the J Button " java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1)."

Comment: Your query has one parameter, you're setting two (an integer and a date)

Comment: And you are selecting an integer and tries to insert it into a column that judging by its name is a date

Comment: i'm trying to do is, get an id from JTextField and select the row that the ID includes, and insert a date to the column(Submit_date) that id includes by a JXDatePicker.

Comment: There is a one JtextField and One JXDatePicker in my GUI, so I need to do is, get an ID from that JTextField and select the Row of DB Table that input id has, and insert the date to DB Table that input id has, by JXDatePicker.

Comment: Are you editing a book or adding a new one?

Comment: My DB Table has four columns, ID, issue_date,Return_date,Submit_date. The submit date column is empty in all records. what i'm trying to do is, get id input by jtextfield and insert submit date where the jtextfiled input id=Tble Id,

Comment: adding and etiting the table in same time. selecti book id from jtextfield and insert submit date by jxdatepicker